# Problem understanding why Math.Pow() puts decimal place in the wrong spot

Tags: c#, math

I am taking a codecademy course and one of the review questions is to make a program that calculates compound interest. I'm being taught methods at the moment, so I'm all over this site and I found an equation for compound interest calculation. I even used the same values. I have the right answer but when I use `Math.Pow()` it puts the decimal in the wrong spot. I've been looking at answers for days and I'm so stuck. I do not want move on until I understand why this happens, and how I can fix it.

Note: we haven't gotten to if/else statements in the course. Just working with variables.

```
double amount = 1000.00;

double intRate = 2.0;

int numYears = 5;

double numTimesCompound = 2.0;

double compTotal1 = amount * (1 + intRate / numTimesCompound);
Console.WriteLine(compTotal1);

double compTotal2 = numTimesCompound * numYears;
Console.WriteLine(compTotal2);

double totIntrest = Math.Pow(compTotal1, compTotal2);

Console.WriteLine(totIntrest);
```

This gives the following output:

```
2000
10
1.024E+33
```

I've tried different methods to resolve the problem. such as `Math.Floor()` and `Math.Abs()`. I've tried changing the variables to decimal, instead of double (which should be correct with money, yes?) and maybe that's my problem. Also at a certain point, I just came here for the answer so I can understand what I'm doing wrong. I've looked through some of the answers and `Math.Round()` seems to have something I'm looking for but what's with the `E+33`?

Comment: An interest rate of 2 equals 200%, not 2%. Are you sure that's what you intended?

Comment: 2% = 0.02, not 0.2

Comment: The E+33 means 10 to the power 33, which is quite a lot

Answer (score 1):

Each year your prevoius `amount` is icreased by `intRate` percent, i.e. instead of initial `100%` you have `100% + intRate`:

```
newAmount = prevAmount * (100 + intRate) / 100 = prevAmount * (1 + intRate / 100)
```

If we want several years we have a telecsopic multiplication:

```
amount_1 = amount_0 * (1 + intRate / 100)
amount_2 = amount_1 * (1 + intRate / 100)
amount_3 = amount_2 * (1 + intRate / 100)
...
amount_n = amount_n_1 * (1 + intRate / 100)
```

So far so good

```
amount_n = amount_0 * (1 + intRate / 100) * ... * (1 + intRate / 100) = 
                      ^                                             ^
                      |---------------    n times    ---------------|  

         = amount_0 * Pow((1 + intRate / 100), n)
```

Let's code:

```
double amount  = 1000.0;
double intRate = 2.0;
int numYears   = 5;

double finalAmount = amount * Math.Pow(1 + intRate / 100.0, numYears);
double interest = finalAmount - amount;

// f2 - let's format (round) up to cents
Console.WriteLine($"After {numYears} years: {finalAmount:f2}");
Console.WriteLine($"Interest {interest:f2}");
```

Figures:

```
After 5 years: 1104.08
Interest 104.08
```

Which are quite realistic (you definitely can't buy the entire Galaxy having invested `1000$` for `5` years for `2%`)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main things that you are missing here.

The formula for compound interest is `P*(1+ r/n)^nt` where P is the starting amount, r is the interest rate, n is the number of times compounded per time period, and t is the number of time periods. In your code you are applying the exponent incorrectly because what you are calculating is `(P*(1 + r/n))^nt` which is including your starting amount in the exponential component which is making your final result much larger than it should be.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, the interest rate should be expressed as a ratio rather than a percentage, so 2% would be 0.02, not 2